# Conditionally replace value in a single row or replace value of following rows with values from previous row group in R

Tags: r, data.table, rows

I have a huge datatable with over 20'000 rows with a column for each time point t and for each customer with id and I am looking for a way to replace the values in y for t=5:8 each customer id by the value by copy pasting the value of y when t=3&4.

The data set below is a short version of my data set:

```
Dt=data.table(
t=rep(1:8, times=3),
y=c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0),
id=rep(1:3, each=8))

   t y id
 1: 1 0  1
 2: 2 1  1
 3: 3 0  1
 4: 4 0  1
 5: 5 0  1
 6: 6 1  1
 7: 7 1  1
 8: 8 0  1
 9: 1 0  2
10: 2 0  2
11: 3 0  2
12: 4 1  2
13: 5 0  2
14: 6 0  2
15: 7 1  2
16: 8 0  2
17: 1 0  3
18: 2 1  3
19: 3 1  3
20: 4 1  3
21: 5 0  3
22: 6 1  3
23: 7 0  3
24: 8 0  3
```

In the end it should look like this:

```
    t y id
 1: 1 0  1
 2: 2 1  1
 3: 3 0  1
 4: 4 0  1
 5: 5 0  1
 6: 6 0  1
 7: 7 0  1
 8: 8 0  1
 9: 1 0  2
10: 2 0  2
11: 3 0  2
12: 4 1  2
13: 5 0  2
14: 6 1  2
15: 7 0  2
16: 8 1  2
17: 1 0  3
18: 2 1  3
19: 3 1  3
20: 4 1  3
21: 5 1  3
22: 6 1  3
23: 7 1  3
24: 8 1  3
```

Do you maybe have an idea how I could solve this? I thought of doing 2 for loops with the range of t and customer id, but I imagine that for this dataset it would take too long.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data does not exactly match what is displayed in your post (particularly rows where `t` is 3 and 4 within `id` 3). You could try `replace` in the following approach, though not sure how efficient this is generating a copy with `:=`.

```
library(data.table)

Dt[ , y := replace(y, t %in% 5:8, y[t %in% 3:4]), by = id]
Dt
```

**Output**

```
    t y id
 1: 1 0  1
 2: 2 1  1
 3: 3 0  1
 4: 4 0  1
 5: 5 0  1
 6: 6 0  1
 7: 7 0  1
 8: 8 0  1
 9: 1 0  2
10: 2 0  2
11: 3 0  2
12: 4 1  2
13: 5 0  2
14: 6 1  2
15: 7 0  2
16: 8 1  2
17: 1 0  3
18: 2 1  3
19: 3 0  3
20: 4 0  3
21: 5 0  3
22: 6 0  3
23: 7 0  3
24: 8 0  3
    t y id
```